# local db connection string does not work but Context Connection does

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, clr

I give up. I have Googled, read numerous SO posts... and I cannot figure this out. I am working in Visual Studio 2012 .NET 3.5 connecting to a local db instance to test with. If I use

```
string cnn = @"Context Connection=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn))
        {
            connection.Open();
```

I connect and my code works. I now need to add a `SqlbulkCopy` to this solution. To do this I switch the connection string to :

```
string cnn = @"Data source= (localdb)\ProjectsV12; Database=TableTesting; Trusted_Connection=True;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn))
        {
            connection.Open();
```

No matter what I do with the connection string I get the following error:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "WorkTable": 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at StoredProcedures.WorkTable(String o)
```

And I just CANNOT figure out how to debug/repair/correct this.

Comment: So it's your contention that the exception is happening on the `connection.Open()` statement?  Also, I don't see `SqlBulkCopy` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Also, is this code that is running in a SQL CLR stored procedure within SQL Server?

Comment: @STLDeveloper yes a CLR sp; when I step through with the debugger the code blows up and returns the error on the `connection.Open()` line. Also, the full code is quite lengthy so I only posted the offending code. The debugger stops right there. If I use the `"Context connection=True"` string then the code runs all the way through (past the `connection.Open()` )until it hits the `SqlBulkCopy` call. It is my understanding the `SqlBulkCopy` does not work with Context Connection. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I've only done a little SQL CLR, and not SqlBulkCopy within that, so not probably going to be of much help. It appears that you have a permissions issue somewhere.  I know that when using a context connection, authentication is bypassed, so maybe that's why the context connection works and the normal connection fails.

Comment: @STLDeveloper agreed this is some sort of permission issue. I just have no idea how to figure out if the local MSSQLEXpress instance installed with VS2012 is the issue or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

After MUCH head-banging confusion... it appears that `PERMISSION LEVEL` needs to be `UNSAFE` AND `TRUSTWORTHY` must be checked for this connection `string string cnn = "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12; Initial Catalog=TableTesting; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";`
to work properly.